# Can't export development iOS App after archiving it

Tags: ios, xcode

I archived my app for testing and then tried to export it.
But Xcode asks me to sign the project again, as it doesn't show my previous developer account.

It says :

> Apple Developer website is undergoing maintenance

But the website and everything in the developer site seems up and fine!! 
Furthermore, I can't believe they have been down for such a long time, it seems there is another problem, because when I try to add the developer account again, it gives me this error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to log in with account 'xxxxx@me.com'.
>   An unexpected failure occurred while logging in (Underlying error code 503).

Anyone knows anything about this mystery? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I came across similar issue today and fixed by force quit xcode, re-open, clean, achieve and export.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error-message seems to be correct. There is currently a scheduled maintenance.

[image: status]

Source: [Apple Developer System Status](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/)